# past simple vs past progressive

Tags: past-simple, past-continuous

> Yesterday Sue ____________ (walk) down the street when she met James. He was going to the station to catch a train, and he was carrying a bag. They stopped to talk for a few minutes.

The correct answer to fill in the blank is "was walking". I understand it.

But I can't explain why "walked" is a wrong answer.

Comment: It's wrong because *when she met James* describes something that happened while something else was in progress - so *walk* needs to be in a progressive tense. If you wanted to use the simple past, you would have to change the sentence to *Yesterday Sue walked down the street and happened to meet James*. The version in your sentence is more natural though.

Comment: @Minty That is not technically true.

Comment: @Lambie which bit?

Comment: @Minty Please read my answer. I walked down the street when I met him. I did not go into the building.

Comment: @Lambie that's not English AFAIC - no disrespect intended but I don't agree.

Comment: @Minty In a description about a past event: She walked down the street when she met him. She didn't walk down the street before that. It's completely English.

Comment: @Lambie still disagree, sorry. For me that could only mean that she met him and then walked down the street (as in *she lowered her bonnet and walked on down the street when she saw him*, but it's a bizarre way to express that. No point in arguing though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the main rules for using the past progressive or continuous (was + gerund) is **when the word when appears.**

- to be doing something when something else occurred.

Most grammars will explain it that way.

The first action was ongoing WHEN the second action occurred. Even if the word when is not specifically mentioned, it can be implied.

- I was eating dinner around 7 o'clock. That describes what you were doing at that time.

[image: time of past continuous from englishpage.com]

There are three basic uses (see that page from englishpage.com for many examples)

- Interrupted action
- Specific time as an interruption
- Parallel actions
- Creating atmosphere

**She walked down the street when she met Steve**. is fine but means:

**She walked down the street *as the result* of meeting or seeing him.**

As in:
She left the room when she saw him.
She paid her bills when they arrived in the mail.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that "walked" is wrong here.

> Yesterday Sue walked down the street when she met James.

seems quite correct to me. However, i think that:

> Yesterday Sue was walking down the street when she met James.

is better because the action of walking was still in progress when Sue met James. Also the next sentence is entirely in the past progressive, so "was walking" is more consistent and flows better.

Comment: I think you've entirely missed the point as made by @Lambie above - if the first of two "simultaneous" actions (***when*** they happened was the same time) is *Simple Past* rather than *Continuous*, the strong implication is that it's an [immediate?] *reaction* to the second action.